# C Programming: Read file and search in a second file based on the data found

Tags: c, regex, file, fgets, scanf

I have two files, file1.txt and file2.txt:

file1.txt:

```
1234:James Smith:100:110
1111:Steve Jones:150:130
4321:Bob Wilson:110:140
```

file2.txt

```
100;Area 1;0.00
110;Area 2;3.00
120;Area 3;4.75
130;Area 4;5.95
140;Area 5;10.00
150;Area 6;12.00
```

What I would like to do is read file1.txt line by line and record some of the information to a file3.txt (output file) such as field 1 (number) and field 2 (name). To test that I could retrieve these, I used:

```
while (fscanf(file1, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%d", number, name, &on, &off) == 4)
{
  printf("Name contains: %s", name);
}
```

As expected, this retrieved all of the "name" (field 2) values and displayed them on screen.
I would now like to use the data stored in "on" and "off" to retrieve additional information from file2.txt. As you can see above, file1.txt fields 3 and 4 match up with field 1 in file2.txt. What I'm looking at getting in the final output file is:

```
1234 James Smith Area 1 to Area 2 3.00
1111 Steve Jones Area 6 to Area 4 6.05
4321 Bob Wilson Area 2 to Area 5 7.00
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish reading file1.txt line by line and performing the "check" with file2.txt at the same time and outputting. I also require a simple subtraction calculation in there as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't have much experience with fscanf, fgets, reading files, etc.

Comment: You've managed to read the first file correctly. You should make an attempt first before asking for help.

Comment: I can definitely read the second file as well using the same format as above. It's just I'm not entirely sure how to read the first line in file1, perform the comparison, do a little calculation, output to the output file then read the second line and so on...

Comment: Define an array of structures for file1 record and file2 record. For each line read store the variables in the next structure in the array. I'm assuming your data files are not large. Then loop through the file1 array of structures. For each record loop through the file2 structures to find any matches.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the struct definitions required-:

```
#define MAX_LINES 1000

struct rec1 
{
   int n;
   char name[30];
   int area1;
   int area2;
};

struct rec1 rec1_list[MAX_LINES];

struct rec2
{
   int area;
   char desc[20];
   int rating;
};

struct rec2 rec2_list[MAX_LINES];
```